# What's the difference between GeForce and Quadro?

Tags: nvidia-geforce, nvidia-quadro

What's the difference between nVidia's GeForce and Quadro lines of graphics cards?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would identify the main difference (if there was only one difference), but [this link](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nvidia.com%2Fobject%2Fquadro_geforce.html&rct=j&q=geforce%20vs%20quadro&ei=p5DhTMPdGISs8AaXr_ED&usg=AFQjCNESkCnpBGLD_XkAyUuFJ4Ky6W-D_g&cad=rja) tells all the differences. I hope this helps.

Comment: Good link.  Covers it well.

Comment: Outdated, but it does really get the point across.  Just ignore some of the technical details.